# Convert dictionary with nested lists to a specific pandas df structure

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, pandas

How can I convert `dictionary` to the "Desired output" below ?

I have a `dictionary` with a nested list as values:

```
dictionary = {'Person1': ['a', 1, 'b', 2], 'Person2': ['c', 3, 'd', 4]}   #(the dict is longer than this, this is just an example)
```

**Desired output:**

| name | letter | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'Person1' | 'a' | 1 |
| 'Person1' | 'b' | 2 |
| 'Person2' | 'c' | 3 |
| 'Person2' | 'd' | 4 |

**Current code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change dictionary to list of tuples by zipping pair and unpairs value of lists in list comprehension and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [(k, *x) for k, v in dictionary.items() for x in zip(v[::2], v[1::2])]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['name','letter','value'])
print (df)
      name letter  value
0  Person1      a      1
1  Person1      b      2
2  Person2      c      3
3  Person2      d      4
```